# Report Viewer (SSRS 2005) Not rendering correctly with update to .Net 3.5

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I'm having an issue with the SSRS 2005 report viewer no longer rendering correctly in the browser. We updated the application that calls the report to use the .Net 3.5 framework and are calling the report from the app via a URL to the report server.

The report generates correctly and the layout is fine, the only issue is the report viewer controls (next/prev page, print, etc) no longer display in the toolbar at the top of the report like they used to. They still show up but with no styling and stacked on top of each other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know this is an old post but we're having the exact same issue and I was wondering if you ever figured out the cause/solution? Thanks,
RTG

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of information you did not specify here to clarify, so I am going to make the following assumptions based on what you wrote:

- you are not using the ReportViewer control from Visual Studio in your web app.
- you are using the URL Access to get to the report (e.g. http://localhost/ReportServer?MyReport&p1=a&p2=b) either in a new window/popup, frame, or iframe.

If that's the case, append the following to your URL and see if you get the toolbar back:
&rs:Toolbar=true

HTH